# Postgres Connection drops after 15 mins of idleness

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, pgbouncer

We have a java application that uses **Postgres v11** along with **PgBouncer** for connection pooling. When we keep the application idle for 15 mins, the connection drops(JDBC). The database is hosted on **Amazon AWS**

The same is observed in Pgadmin.

We tried TCP keepalive and few others. Nothing works.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is probably a timeout configured in pgBouncer

Comment: ... or on a firewall.

Comment: What messages do you get, both on the server and the client?

Comment: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occured while sending to the backend.` in the client. I can't find the server logs

Answer (score 0):

Most connection pools have setting like "keep alive time", "keep alive query".
You can set them in the Java application to prevent network timeout.

For example, for HikariCP:

- keepaliveTime - "This property controls how frequently HikariCP will attempt to keep a connection alive, in order to prevent it from being timed out by the database or network infrastructure"

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#frequently-used

Comment: I don't think `HikariCP` is needed. Because we already have `Pgbouncer` which already does the connection pooling, isn't it?